# List concatenation in python

Tags: python-3.x

I know that list is a mutable object in python. Then why does it assign a new location for a list variable when I concatenate list elements.Why doesn't myList add the contents on the original object instead of creating a new object?

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
def proc(myList):
     myList = myList + [6, 7]
     print(myList)


 print (list1)
 proc(list1)
 print (list1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because assignment doesn't mutate, it rebinds.

```
myList.extend([6, 7])
```

Comment: or `myList += [6, 7]` - whatever floats his boat

Comment: Can you explain rebind? also what's the difference between append and extend?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073995/difference-between-mutation-rebinding-copying-value-and-assignment-operator

Comment: http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~selfpace/cs9honline/Q2/mutation.html.