# How do change the list value?

Tags: python

```
def double_reverse(words_list):
    reverse = []
    reverse1= []
    reverse = words_list[::-1] 
    
    for i in reverse:
        reverse1.append(i[::-1])
    words_list = reverse1
```

Hi there,

I have this question for a practice assessment:

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqsc7.png)

For this question, I cannot return or print anything. Instead, I need to update the words_list list value so that I can get the desired result.

However, for some reason I can only get the original list. Why is the list not being updated?

Cheers

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67363959/14429185) will help you.

Comment: Assigning to the `words_list` variable within `double_reverse` has no effect outside of that function.  Instead, you need to modify the list that `words_list` references, modifying it in-place.  That way, any other references to that list will see the changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I unable to return a list of words after I've reversed the order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67363816/why-am-i-unable-to-return-a-list-of-words-after-ive-reversed-the-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
words_list = reverse1
```

just **rebinds** the local variable `words_list`. It does not **mutate** the object that this variable referenced before (the one that got passed in as a function argument). A simple fix would be slice assignment:

```
words_list[:] = reverse1
```

which constitutes a mutation on said object.

A general pythonic simplification of your function could be:

```
def double_reverse(words_list):
    words_list[:] = [w[::-1] for w in reversed(words_list)]
```

Comment: Thanks very much, sorry for the naivety but what do you mean by rebind and mutate?

Comment: There is plenty of material on that topic =) e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073995/difference-between-mutation-rebinding-copying-value-and-assignment-operator or https://frecar.no/mutation-rebinding-python/ (or any other google result)