# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment for one variable whilst other works in Python

Tags: python, local-variables

How come I get local variable referenced before assignment error for `cur_max` while i can use `copy_matrix` within the `dfs` function?

```
class Solution:
    def longestIncreasingPath(self, matrix: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        rows, columns = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])
        copy_matrix = {}
        cur_max = 0
        
        def dfs(r, c, prev):
            if (r < 0 or c < 0 or
                r == rows or c == columns or
                matrix[r][c] <= prev):
                return 0
            
            if (r, c) in copy_matrix:
                return copy_matrix[(r, c)]
            
            max_length = 0
            max_length = max(max_length, 1 + dfs(r + 1, c, matrix[r][c]))
            max_length = max(max_length, 1 + dfs(r - 1, c, matrix[r][c]))
            max_length = max(max_length, 1 + dfs(r, c + 1, matrix[r][c]))
            max_length = max(max_length, 1 + dfs(r, c - 1, matrix[r][c]))
            copy_matrix[(r, c)] = max_length
            cur_max = max(cur_max, copy_matrix[(r, c)])
            
            return max_length
        
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(columns):
                dfs(r, c, -1)
        
        return max(copy_matrix.values())
```

here's what i get

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cur_max' referenced before assignment
    cur_max = max(cur_max, copy_matrix[(r, c)])
Line 22 in dfs (Solution.py)
    dfs(r, c, -1)
Line 28 in longestIncreasingPath (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().longestIncreasingPath(param_1)
Line 49 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 60 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: what i eventually would like to return is ```cur_max``` not ```max(copy_matrix.values())```

Comment: @KlausD. added.

Comment: Your traceback is as incomplete as your code, or is it upside down?

Comment: @KlausD. what do you mean it's incomplete? that's what I get.

Comment: oh i see what you mean, yes its upside down

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. Also, search for the error message to find literally hundreds of similar questions.

Comment: While a minimal reproducible example is needed, this is a good question, other question related to this local variable error, that I have seen are not related to nested functions(there might be some out there which don' t come up on searching the error though)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073995. Claiming that you are "using" one variable successfully but not the other, hides critical information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because for `copy_matrix` there is no local variable there, so it references the `nonlocal` variable present at line 6 ie `copy_matrix = {}`, while for `cur_max` it is being defined as a local variable in line 24 ie `cur_max = max(cur_max, copy_matrix[(r, c)])`, it is referencing nonlocal variables for `copy_matirx`, `rows`, `columns` but it is referencing the local variable for `cur_max` because it is being defined in the function and being referenced before assignment. What you probably want to do is this

```py
def dfs(r, c, prev):
    nonlocal cur_max
    if (r < 0 or c < 0 or
        r == rows or c == columns or
        matrix[r][c] <= prev):
        return 0
    
    if (r, c) in copy_matrix:
        return copy_matrix[(r, c)]
    
    max_length = 0
    max_length = max(max_length, 1 + dfs(r + 1, c, matrix[r][c]))
    max_length = max(max_length, 1 + dfs(r - 1, c, matrix[r][c]))
    max_length = max(max_length, 1 + dfs(r, c + 1, matrix[r][c]))
    max_length = max(max_length, 1 + dfs(r, c - 1, matrix[r][c]))
    copy_matrix[(r, c)] = max_length
    cur_max = max(cur_max, copy_matrix[(r, c)])
    
    return max_length
```

[read more](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)