# Python: list of lists

Tags: python

Running the code

```
listoflists = []
list = []
for i in range(0,10):
    list.append(i)
    if len(list)>3:
        list.remove(list[0])
        listoflists.append((list, list[0]))
print listoflists
```

returns

```
[([7, 8, 9], 0), ([7, 8, 9], 0), ([7, 8, 9], 0), ([7, 8, 9], 1), ([7, 8, 9], 2), ([7, 8, 9], 3), ([7, 8, 9], 4), ([7, 8, 9], 5), ([7, 8, 9], 6), ([7, 8, 9], 7)]
```

so somehow the first argument of each tuple (list) is being updated each time in the list of lists, but the second argument list[0] is not. Can someone explain what's going on here and suggest a way to fix this? I'd like to output

```
[([0],0), ([0,1],0), ...
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8997559/1142167

Comment: You need to expand your example desired output. What you seem to want (from your code and your description) does not match the example.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Lists are a mutable type - in order to create a copy (rather than just passing the same list around), you need to do so explicitly:

```
listoflists.append((list[:], list[0]))
```

However, `list` is already the name of a Python built-in - it'd be better not to use that name for your variable. Here's a version that doesn't use `list` as a variable name, and makes a copy:

```
listoflists = []
a_list = []
for i in range(0,10):
    a_list.append(i)
    if len(a_list)>3:
        a_list.remove(a_list[0])
        listoflists.append((list(a_list), a_list[0]))
print listoflists
```

---

Note that I demonstrated two different ways to make a copy of a list above: `[:]` and `list()`.

The first, `[:]`, is creating a *slice* (normally often used for getting just part of a list), which happens to contain the entire list, and thus is effectively a copy of the list.

The second, `list()`, is using the actual `list` *type constructor* to create a new list which has contents equal to the first list. (I didn't use it in the first example because you were overwriting that name in your code - which is a good example of why you don't want to do that!)

Comment: `len(listoflists)` will return how many lists are inside of listoflists.

Answer (score 25):

I came here because I'm new with python and lazy so I was searching an example to create a list of 2 lists, after a while a realized the topic here could be wrong...
This is a code to create a list of lists:

```py
listoflists = []
for i in range(0,2):
    sublist = []
    for j in range(0,10)
        sublist.append((i,j))
    listoflists.append(sublist)
print listoflists
```

this is the output:

```py
[
    [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9)],
    [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9)]
]
```

The problem with your code seems to be you are creating a tuple with your list and you get the reference to the list instead of a copy. That I guess should fall under a tuple topic...

Comment: This doesn't give the output the OP asked for.

Comment: right, but I thought this better matches the title of the question than the question itself and normally people land here because they want just create a list of list and not because they have problems updating a list of tuples... probably because I use this site as a learning tool and not as a debugger tool :-)

Answer (score 13):

First, I strongly recommend that you rename your variable `list` to something else. `list` is the name of the built-in list constructor, and you're hiding its normal function. I will rename `list` to `a` in the following.

Python names are *references* that are bound to objects. That means that unless you create more than one list, whenever you use `a` it's referring to the same actual list object as last time. So when you call

```
listoflists.append((a, a[0]))
```

you can later change `a` and it changes what the first element of that tuple points to. This does not happen with `a[0]` because the object (which is an integer) pointed to by `a[0]` doesn't change (although `a[0]` points to different objects over the run of your code).

You can create a *copy* of the whole list `a` using the `list` constructor:

```
listoflists.append((list(a), a[0]))
```

Or, you can use the *slice notation* to make a copy:

```
listoflists.append((a[:], a[0]))
```

Answer (score 3):

When you run the code

```
listoflists.append((list, list[0]))
```

You are not (as I think you expect) adding a copy of `list` to the end of `listoflists`. What you are doing is adding a reference to `list` to the end of `listoflists`. Thus, every time you update `list`, it updates every reference to `list`, which in this case, is every item in `listoflists`

What you could do instead is something like this:

```
listoflists = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    listoflists.append((range(i), 0))
```

Answer (score 3):

The *list* variable (which I would recommend to rename to something more sensible) is a reference to a list object, which can be changed.

On the line

```
listoflists.append((list, list[0]))
```

You actually are only adding a reference to the object reference by the list variable. You've got multiple possibilities to create a copy of the list, so *listoflists* contains the values as you seem to expect:

**Use the copy library**

```
import copy
listoflists.append((copy.copy(list), list[0]))
```

**use the slice notation**

```
listoflists.append((list[:], list[0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're also not going to get the output you're hoping for as long as you append to listoflists only inside the if-clause.

Try something like this instead:

```
import copy

listoflists = []
list = []
for i in range(0,10):
    list.append(i)
    if len(list)>3:
        list.remove(list[0])
    listoflists.append((copy.copy(list), copy.copy(list[0])))
print(listoflists)
```

Answer (score 2):

Time traveller here

```
List_of_list =[([z for z in range(x-2,x+1) if z >= 0],y) for y in range(10) for x in range(10)]
```

This should do the trick. And the output is this:

```
[([0], 0), ([0, 1], 0), ([0, 1, 2], 0), ([1, 2, 3], 0), ([2, 3, 4], 0),  ([3, 4, 5], 0), ([4, 5, 6], 0), ([5, 6, 7], 0), ([6, 7, 8], 0), ([7, 8, 9], 0), ([0], 1), ([0, 1], 1), ([0, 1, 2], 1), ([1, 2, 3], 1), ([2, 3, 4], 1), ([3, 4, 5], 1), ([4, 5, 6], 1), ([5, 6, 7], 1), ([6, 7, 8], 1), ([7, 8, 9], 1), ([0], 2), ([0, 1], 2), ([0, 1, 2], 2), ([1, 2, 3], 2), ([2, 3, 4], 2), ([3, 4, 5], 2), ([4, 5, 6], 2), ([5, 6, 7], 2), ([6, 7, 8], 2), ([7, 8, 9], 2), ([0], 3), ([0, 1], 3), ([0, 1, 2], 3), ([1, 2, 3], 3), ([2, 3, 4], 3), ([3, 4, 5], 3), ([4, 5, 6], 3), ([5, 6, 7], 3), ([6, 7, 8], 3), ([7, 8, 9], 3), ([0], 4), ([0, 1], 4), ([0, 1, 2], 4), ([1, 2, 3], 4), ([2, 3, 4], 4), ([3, 4, 5], 4), ([4, 5, 6], 4), ([5, 6, 7], 4), ([6, 7, 8], 4), ([7, 8, 9], 4), ([0], 5), ([0, 1], 5), ([0, 1, 2], 5), ([1, 2, 3], 5), ([2, 3, 4], 5), ([3, 4, 5], 5), ([4, 5, 6], 5), ([5, 6, 7], 5), ([6, 7, 8], 5), ([7, 8, 9], 5), ([0], 6), ([0, 1], 6), ([0, 1, 2], 6), ([1, 2, 3], 6), ([2, 3, 4], 6), ([3, 4, 5], 6), ([4, 5, 6], 6), ([5, 6, 7], 6), ([6, 7, 8], 6), ([7, 8, 9], 6), ([0], 7), ([0, 1], 7), ([0, 1, 2], 7), ([1, 2, 3], 7), ([2, 3, 4], 7), ([3, 4, 5], 7), ([4, 5, 6], 7), ([5, 6, 7], 7), ([6, 7, 8], 7), ([7, 8, 9], 7), ([0], 8), ([0, 1], 8), ([0, 1, 2], 8), ([1, 2, 3], 8), ([2, 3, 4], 8), ([3, 4, 5], 8), ([4, 5, 6], 8), ([5, 6, 7], 8), ([6, 7, 8], 8), ([7, 8, 9], 8), ([0], 9), ([0, 1], 9), ([0, 1, 2], 9), ([1, 2, 3], 9), ([2, 3, 4], 9), ([3, 4, 5], 9), ([4, 5, 6], 9), ([5, 6, 7], 9), ([6, 7, 8], 9), ([7, 8, 9], 9)]
```

This is done by list comprehension(which makes looping elements in a list via one line code possible). The logic behind this one-line code is the following:

(1) for x in range(10) and for y in range(10) are employed for two independent loops inside a list

(2) (a list, y) is the general term of the loop, which is why it is placed before two for's in (1)

(3) the length of the list in (2) cannot exceed 3, and the list depends on x, so

```
[z for z in range(x-2,x+1)]
```

is used

(4) because z starts from zero but range(x-2,x+1) starts from -2 which isn't what we want, so a conditional statement if z >= 0 is placed at the end of the list in (2)

```
[z for z in range(x-2,x+1) if z >= 0]
```