# Extracting a scientific notation number using regexp in python

Tags: python, qregexp

I'm trying to extract values from numerous text files in python. The numbers I require are in the scientific notation form. My result text files are as follows

```
    ADDITIONAL DATA

Tip Rotation (degrees)
Node    , UR[x] , UR[y] , UR[z]
21  , 1.0744    , 1.2389    , -4.3271
22  , -1.0744   , -1.2389   , -4.3271
53  , 0.9670    , 1.0307    , -3.8990
54  , -0.0000   , -0.0000   , -3.5232
55  , -0.9670   , -1.0307   , -3.8990

Mean rotation variation along blade
Region  , Rotation (degrees)
Partition line 0,   7.499739E-36
Partition line 1,   -3.430092E-01
Partition line 2,   -1.019287E+00
Partition line 3,   -1.499808E+00
Partition line 4,   -1.817651E+00
Partition line 5,   -2.136372E+00
Partition line 6,   -2.448321E+00
Partition line 7,   -2.674414E+00
Partition line 8,   -2.956737E+00
Partition line 9,   -3.457806E+00
Partition line 10,  -3.995106E+00
```

I've been using regexp successfully in the past but its doesnt seem to want to pick up the numbers. The number of the nodes changes in my results file so can't search by line. My python script is as follows.

```
import re
from pylab import *
from scipy import *
import matplotlib
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import csv

########################################

minTheta        = -90
maxTheta        = 0
thetaIncrements = 10

numberOfPartitions = 10

########################################

numberOfThetas = ((maxTheta - minTheta)/thetaIncrements)+1
print 'Number of thetas = '+str(numberOfThetas)

thetas              = linspace(minTheta,maxTheta,numberOfThetas)
print 'Thetas = '+str(thetas)
part                = linspace(1,numberOfPartitions,numberOfPartitions)
print 'Parts = '+str(part)

meanRotations       = np.zeros((numberOfPartitions+1,numberOfThetas))
#print meanRotations

theta = minTheta
n=0
m=0
while theta <= maxTheta:

        fileName = str(theta)+'.0.txt'
        #print fileName

        regexp = re.compile(r'Partition line 0, .*?([-+0-9.E]+)')
        with open(fileName) as f:
            for line in f:
                match = regexp.match(line)
                if match:
                    print (float((match.group(1))))
                    meanRotations[0,m]=(float((match.group(1))))

        regexp = re.compile(r'Partition line 1, .*?([-+0-9.E]+)')
        with open(fileName) as f:
            for line in f:
                match = regexp.match(line)
                if match:
                    print (float((match.group(1))))
                    meanRotations[1,m]=(float((match.group(1))))

        regexp = re.compile(r'Partition line 2, .*?([-+0-9.E]+)')
        with open(fileName) as f:
            for line in f:
                match = regexp.match(line)
                if match:
                    print (float((match.group(1))))
                    meanRotations[2,m]=(float((match.group(1))))

        regexp = re.compile(r'Partition line 3, .*?([-+0-9.E]+)')
        with open(fileName) as f:
            for line in f:
                match = regexp.match(line)
                if match:
                    print (float((match.group(1))))
                    meanRotations[3,m]=(float((match.group(1))))

        regexp = re.compile(r'Partition line 4, .*?([-+0-9.E]+)')
        with open(fileName) as f:
            for line in f:
                match = regexp.match(line)
                if match:
                    print (float((match.group(1))))
                    meanRotations[4,m]=(float((match.group(1))))

        regexp = re.compile(r'Partition line 5, .*?([-+0-9.E]+)')
        with open(fileName) as f:
            for line in f:
                match = regexp.match(line)
                if match:
                    print (float((match.group(1))))
                    meanRotations[5,m]=(float((match.group(1))))

        regexp = re.compile(r'Partition line 6, .*?([-+0-9.E]+)')
        with open(fileName) as f:
            for line in f:
                match = regexp.match(line)
                if match:
                    print (float((match.group(1))))
                    meanRotations[6,m]=(float((match.group(1))))

        regexp = re.compile(r'Partition line 7, .*?([-+0-9.E]+)')
        with open(fileName) as f:
            for line in f:
                match = regexp.match(line)
                if match:
                    print (float((match.group(1))))
                    meanRotations[7,m]=(float((match.group(1))))

        regexp = re.compile(r'Partition line 8, .*?([-+0-9.E]+)')
        with open(fileName) as f:
            for line in f:
                match = regexp.match(line)
                if match:
                    print (float((match.group(1))))
                    meanRotations[8,m]=(float((match.group(1))))

        regexp = re.compile(r'Partition line 9, .*?([-+0-9.E]+)')
        with open(fileName) as f:
            for line in f:
                match = regexp.match(line)
                if match:
                    print (float((match.group(1))))
                    meanRotations[9,m]=(float((match.group(1))))

        regexp = re.compile(r'Partition line 10, .*?([-+0-9.E]+)')
        with open(fileName) as f:
            for line in f:
                match = regexp.match(line)
                if match:
                    print (float((match.group(1))))
                    meanRotations[10,m]=(float((match.group(1))))

        m=m+1
        theta = theta+thetaIncrements

print 'Mean rotations on partition lines = '
print meanRotations
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: why not get rid of the header ('Partition line x') and just use re.findall() instead?

Comment: This can be simplified with a loop. It makes no sense to write the same code 10 times.

Comment: It also makes not sense to open and iterate the file n times.

Comment: Also, check your imports. This kind of imports `from pylab import *` are not recommended. And you're importing the same modules twice.

Comment: Diego, I did use a loop at first but when it wasn't working I decided to make sure that wasn't the problem so wrote it in full.

Corley, there is more data in the results file than just what I've shown, would this affect what your proposing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the need for regex, to be honest. Something like this should do what you need:

```
with open(fileName) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('Partition line'):
            number=float(line.split(',')[1])
            print number # or do whatever you want with it
        # read other file contents with different if clauses
```

Comment: That did the tricks, thanks. But how could I put those values in a matrix form, i.e every file has its own row and every partition line its own column (or vice versa). So I would be looking at a n*11 matrix with n=number of files?

Comment: Either you use a matrix/array type of your choice (e.g. from  [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array)), and fill it up successively, or you make a list of lists, and for every file you load, append the list full of partition line entries to that object.
The latter is a bit tricky, though, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487049/python-list-of-lists/11487098

Comment: Thanks for the help, but thought of another way, make one big list then reshape it to size! Any idea how to take one row value away from the above value to produce a difference in the rows and subsequently produce a matrix with 1 less row?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but Numpy.diff seems to be what you want: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html

Answer (score 4):

Is this format of file standard one? If so? you can get all your float values with another technic. 
So, here is the code:

```py
str = """    ADDITIONAL DATA

Tip Rotation (degrees)
Node    , UR[x] , UR[y] , UR[z]
21  , 1.0744    , 1.2389    , -4.3271
22  , -1.0744   , -1.2389   , -4.3271
53  , 0.9670    , 1.0307    , -3.8990
54  , -0.0000   , -0.0000   , -3.5232
55  , -0.9670   , -1.0307   , -3.8990

Mean rotation variation along blade
Region  , Rotation (degrees)
Partition line 0,   7.499739E-36
Partition line 1,   -3.430092E-01
Partition line 2,   -1.019287E+00
Partition line 3,   -1.499808E+00
Partition line 4,   -1.817651E+00
Partition line 5,   -2.136372E+00
Partition line 6,   -2.448321E+00
Partition line 7,   -2.674414E+00
Partition line 8,   -2.956737E+00
Partition line 9,   -3.457806E+00
Partition line 10,  -3.995106E+00
"""

arr = str.split()
for index in enumerate(arr):
    print index  # just to see the list
start = 59  # from this position the numbers begin
step = 4    # current number is each fourth
ar = []
for j in range(start, len(arr), step):
    ar.append(arr[j])

floatAr = []
# or you can use this expression instead of the following loop 
# floatAr = [float(x) for x in ar]
for n in range(len(ar)):
    floatAr.append(float(ar[n]))

print floatAr
```

At the end you will recive a list called **floatAr** with all your float values. You can add *try-except* block for better usability.

Or, alternatively, if you want to use regex, here is the code:

```
<!--language:python -->

str = """   ADDITIONAL DATA

Tip Rotation (degrees)
Node    , UR[x] , UR[y] , UR[z]
21  , 1.0744    , 1.2389    , -4.3271
22  , -1.0744   , -1.2389   , -4.3271
53  , 0.9670    , 1.0307    , -3.8990
54  , -0.0000   , -0.0000   , -3.5232
55  , -0.9670   , -1.0307   , -3.8990

Mean rotation variation along blade
Region  , Rotation (degrees)
Partition line 0,   7.499739E-36
Partition line 1,   -3.430092E-01
Partition line 2,   -1.019287E+00
Partition line 3,   -1.499808E+00
Partition line 4,   -1.817651E+00
Partition line 5,   -2.136372E+00
Partition line 6,   -2.448321E+00
Partition line 7,   -2.674414E+00
Partition line 8,   -2.956737E+00
Partition line 9,   -3.457806E+00
Partition line 10,  -3.995106E+00"""

regex = '\s-?[1-9]+[0-9]*.?[0-9]*E-?\+?[0-9]+\s?'

import re

values = re.findall(regex, str)
floatAr = [float(x) for x in values]
print floatAr
```

By the way, here is a good on-line regex checker for python [pythex](https://pythex.org/)