# maximum length of a column in a list of lists

Tags: python, string, formatting

Given the example of a list of lists:

```
['| A   | B   |\n| CCC | DDD |\n'])
```

how can I find the max column width for every column, to print it out as a 2D-table as such, with all the correct spaces in between.

```
| A   | B   |
| CCC | DDD |
```

Comment: The example you gave is not a list of lists. Please correct that either the statement.

Answer (score 2):

From the example that the OP is showing in the question, actually it seems that the table is encoded in a string, where columns are divided by '|' and rows are divided by '\n'.

Given this setup (please, OP, fix it in the question), one possible way, after converting the table from string to actual list of lists, is to iterate every each row and identify the length of each element in each column and change the sizes accordingly. Then, print every element of the table with the information about the width of each column.

In the following, functions implementing the general description of the algorithm are (the different aspects are broken down for modularity and for making the learning easier for the OP):

- Transformation of the table in string format to list of lists, namely list of rows, and each row contains a string with the actual element at a given column:

  ```
  def transform_string_to_list_of_lists(input_string):
      rows = input_string.strip().split('\n')
      list_of_lists = []
      last_size = 0
      for i, row in enumerate(rows):
          row_list = [col.strip() for col in row[1:-2].split('|')]
          if i == 0:
              last_size = len(row_list)
          else:
              if len(row_list) != last_size:
                  print("Not a matrix")
                  return None        
          list_of_lists.append(row_list)
      return list_of_lists
  ```

  There are three different components to pay attention to in this function:

  - the string is stripped of the last '\n' as otherwise it would result in an extra empty row;
  - the row string is stripped of the first and last '|', and also each element is stripped of whitespaces;
  - there is a check on whether the number of columns in each row is the same or not.
- Find the maximum width of each column, which returns a list, whose size is the number of columns, and that contains the maximum width for each column:

  ```
  def find_each_column_width(input_table):
      columns_size = [0] * len(input_table[0])
      for row in input_table:      
          for j, column_element in enumerate(row):
              columns_size[j] = max(columns_size[j], len(column_element))
      return columns_size
  ```

  Note the way that `columns_size` is initialized. Also note that the check about the consistency of the table is done when the list of lists is actually created.
- Return the string containing the formatted table:

  ```
  def print_formatted_table(input_table, columns_width):
      output_table_string = ""
      for row in input_table:
          for i, element in enumerate(row):
              output_table_string = output_table_string + "| " + element.ljust(columns_width[i])
          output_table_string += " |\n"
      return output_table_string
  ```

  Note [`ljust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) adds some trailing spaces to the string.

An example of calling of such functions is:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":       
    input_table_in_string = '| A | B |\n| CCC | DDD |\n'
    input_table = transform_string_to_list_of_lists(input_table_in_string)
    columns_width = find_each_column_width(input_table)
    print(print_formatted_table(input_table, columns_width))
```

which results in the following output:

```
| A  | B   |
| CCC| DDD |
```

Note that if a list of tables is provided, then it is sufficient to iterate through that list and calling such functions to print them properly.

Comment: This is an excellent answer (I believe this is probably what the initial question meant to ask): descriptive variable names, good use of the enumerate built-in function. Very well written.

Answer (score 1):

Given example in your question is not the list of lists. you can check this question to create the list of lists

[Python: list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487049/python-list-of-lists)

You can print out the string in this way:

```
d = []
d.append('| A   | B   |\n| CCC | DDD |\n')

col = d[0].split('\n')
temp=0
string =""
for i in col:
    print i
```

Split the string from '\n' store it in an array and print out the elements of array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the following script:

```
import csv
import StringIO


def write_cols(data, col_spacer='|'):
    widths = [0] * len(data[0])

    for row in data:
        widths[:] = [max(widths[index], len(str(col))) for index, col in enumerate(row)]

    return [col_spacer + col_spacer.join("{:<{width}}".format(col, width=widths[index]) for index, col in enumerate(row)) + col_spacer for row in data]


col_data = ['| A | B |\n| CCC | DDD |\n']
rows = col_data[0].split('\n')
cells = []

for row in csv.reader(rows, delimiter='|'):
    if len(row):
        cells.append([cell.strip() for cell in row[1:-1]])

for row in write_cols(cells):
    print row
```

This works in two parts, firstly it strips of all the padding from the original data to create a proper list of lists in the form `[['A', 'B'], ['CCC', 'DDD']]`. This is then passed to `write_cols()` which returns the data correctly padded based on the maximum width of each column. Giving you the following kind of output:

```
|A  |B  |
|CCC|DDD|
```

Changing it `write_cols(cells, " | ")` would give you:

```
 | A   | B   | 
 | CCC | DDD |
```