# python: how to append multiple lists to one

Tags: python

I have a list that should contain all my other lists. Currently I append every list separately but that just looks pretty ugly..

```
looplist = []  # initiate an empty list that contains all date from the other lists 
[...]
looplist.append(internallist1)
[...]
looplist.append(internallist10)
```

the internallists are all getting initialized and filled in a for loop

Comment: you can just `+` them (EDIT: if I understand what you're trying to do correctly, i'm not sure why you have a list of lists to begin with so perhaps this isn't your solution)

Comment: I actually don't know what is wrong with the approach OP is using or why he wants to change it, or what he's expecting to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `zip` method could work for you as you stated your output should:

> look something like [ [list1], [list2], ... , [list n] ]

in your case the code would be similar to

```
looplist = list(zip(internallist1,[...], internallist10))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `+` to merge them.

[You may check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-concatenate-two-lists-in-python) for more info.

If you want to have list of lists, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487049/python-list-of-lists) topic.

Comment: I want to have lists within the looplist, so the final structure should look something like [ [list1], [list2], ... , [list n] ].

Answer (score 1):

```
listOne.extend(anotherList)
```

this could help you: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

you can also do `listOne+=anotherList` and this is less expensive, as it doesn`t involve a function call like `extend`

Comment: `list+=anotherList` looks like you're using `list` as a variable name, which is obviously a bad idea.

Comment: Assuming that OP's code works but is ugly, this will _not_ work as `extend` does something different than `append` (as does `+`).

Comment: can you please elaborate? @tobias_k

Comment: It\`s a generic way, he can use this piece of code inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

To answer what you are asking, Just initialize looplist with your 10 lists.

```
looplist = [internallist1,
            internallist2,
            internallist3] #Note: internallist3,] is also valid, python allows trailing comma. Nifty!
```

However, your 10 lists really shouldn't be separately named lists in the first place if this is your real use case. Just use `looplist[0] through looplist[9]` instead from the get go.