# How to make a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

Is there some way to create a list of lists in Python?  Analogous to `zeroes` or similar functions.

What I am thinking of is something like this (pseudocode to follow):

```
def listoflists(nlists, nitems, fill)
    ...

listoflists(2,3, -1) # returns [[-1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487049/python-list-of-lists)

Comment: Have you done any research? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there's a library function to do it, but here's how I would do it:

`def listoflists(nList, nItem, fill):
    return [[fill for _ in range(nItem)] for _ in range(nList)]`

This uses list comprehension to make a list of size `nItem` `nList` times.

Comment: Using the same variable name for both loops is a bad habit, to say the least. By convention, variables named `_` are unused, which is what you should do here.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list

`root_list = []`

and just append your sublists

`root_list.append([1, 1, 1])`

Answer (score 0):

just need to do this:

```
def list_of_list(n_list, n_elements, fill):
  x = [fill] * n_elements
  y = [x] * n_list
  return y

print(list_of_list(2, 3, -1))
```

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, thanks!

```
def listoflists(nlists, nitems, fill):
    f_list = []
    for i in range(nlists):
        n_list = []
        for j in range(nitems):
            n_list.append(fill)
        f_list.append(n_list)
        n_list = []
    return f_list

print(listoflists(2,3,-1))
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help!  I'm new here so I can't upvote you yet, so just leaving a word of thanks.