# I want to create a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I know there is quite a number of similar questions on stackoverflow but they don't seem to be solving my problem. If you look at my code below, you can see that I am creating a temp list of ads called "tempAdList" and when the if condition evaluate true I am creating a list of lists called "ad_list". I am appending to "ad_list" so I am expecting that everytime the "if statement" evaluates true a new list of 4 ads is appended to "ad_list" but for whatever reason I am getting below output which is not what i am looking for. what am I doing wrong here?

```
ads = Advert.objects.all()

counter = 1
tempAdList = []
ad_list = []

for i, ad in enumerate(ads):
    tempAdList.append(ad)
    if counter == 4:
        # print(tempAdList)
        ad_list.append(tempAdList)
        print(ad_list)
        tempAdList.clear()
        counter = 0
    counter += 1

    adsNum = len(ads)
    # print("i = {} and adsNum = {}".format(i, adsNum))
    if i == adsNum -1 and adsNum % 4 != 0:
        ad_list.append(tempAdList)
```

output:[image]

Comment: Please provide sample input or run case and desired output.

Comment: please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11487104/2950427) you will find this question has been answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `clear`-method on a list also affects all references to it, e.g.

```
>>a = [1, 2, 3]
>>b = a
>>a.clear()
>>print('a =',a)
a = []
>>print('b =',b)
b = []
```

So what you are doing in `ad_list.append(tempAdList)` is to repeatedly add references to the same object to `ad_list`, i.e. each time you update `tempAdList`, the same update is done for each of those references. What you really want to do is reset `tempAdList` with a new object, so replace `tempAdList.clear()` with `tempAdList=[]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of lists, where inner lists are having 4 elements.
You can try something like :

```
new_list = [ads[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(ads), 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you do `tempAdlist.clear()`, you cleared all elements of the list. But because you appended the list to ad_list, you basically cleared it there too. so you have one less list. This is because of the nature of lists being referenced instead of recreated. What you want is to create a list from tempAdlist when appending, like so: `ad_list.append(list(tempAdlist))` this way it will be a whole new list from the tempAdlist. Essentially your code becomes:

```py
ads = Advert.objects.all()

counter = 1
tempAdList = []
ad_list = []

for i, ad in enumerate(ads):
    tempAdList.append(ad)
    if counter == 4:
        # print(tempAdList)
        ad_list.append(list(tempAdList))
        print(ad_list)
        tempAdList.clear()
        counter = 0
    counter += 1

    adsNum = len(ads)
    # print("i = {} and adsNum = {}".format(i, adsNum))
    if i == adsNum -1 and adsNum % 4 != 0:
        ad_list.append(list(tempAdList))
```