# Python list aliasing or global variables in OO programming. Different result, same process

Tags: python, oop, global-variables, alias

I'm aware that a+=b and a=a+b do not always give the same result, depending on what they reference (correct me if I'm wrong here). 
I'm also aware of list aliasing issues in Python. see here: [(Yet Another) List Aliasing Conundrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997559/yet-another-list-aliasing-conundrum)

The problem below seems to be neither of these, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

I have the following program.  Pay special attention to the last line of **add_clouds()** and the last line of **add_hosts()**.

## define the globals and classes here

```
global REQUESTS 
global CLOUDS

REQUESTS = []
CLOUDS = []

class Cloud:

    def __init__(self, ID, coordinate, Hosts):
        self.ID = ID
        self.coordinate = coordinate # coordinate should be a tuple 
        self.Hosts = Hosts # Hosts should be a list of Host objects 

class Host:

    def __init__(self, ID, Resources, Cloud):
        self.ID = ID
        self.Resources = Resources # coordinate should be a tuple 
        self.Cloud = Cloud # Cloud object (NOT the Cloud ID)
```

## This part generates the clouds and hosts

```
def add_cloud(ID,coordinate,Hosts=[]):
    global CLOUDS
    CLOUDS += [Cloud(ID, coordinate,  Hosts)]

def add_host(Cloud_ID, Resources):
    # search CLOUDS for Cloud_ID
    Cloud = getCloud(Cloud_ID)
    ID = len(Cloud.Hosts)+1
    Cloud.Hosts += [Host(ID,Resources,Cloud)]

def getCloud(ID):
    # returns cloud with ID provided 
    for cloud in CLOUDS:
        if ID == cloud.ID:
            return cloud

add_cloud(1,(10.7,13.5))
add_cloud(2,(1.8,3.0))
add_host(1,128)
```

## Result in shell:

```
>>> CLOUDS
[<Cloud_Traversal.Cloud instance at 0x027336C0>, <Cloud_Traversal.Cloud instance at 0x02733DF0>]
>>> CLOUDS[1].Hosts
[<Cloud_Traversal.Host instance at 0x027334E0>]
>>> CLOUDS[0].Hosts
[<Cloud_Traversal.Host instance at 0x027334E0>]
>>>
```

You can see that the host is somehow added to both clouds, even though I only explicitly add it to one (in the line **add_host(1,128)**).

I've tried to see if this is an aliasing issue, but I don't think I'm breaking any rules here.  Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: I see what you all are saying about the default argument being an empty list.  Thanks.  However, when I change the last line of `add_host()` to the following, it gives the correct result:            `Cloud.Hosts = Cloud.Hosts + [Host(ID,Resources,Cloud)]`.  It doesn't seem to me like this relates to the default parameter, so I'm not sure why it solves the problem.

Comment: ...I should have mentioned this is **without** changing the default argument to `None` as suggested.

Comment: That's because `list1 += list2` appends the contents of `list2` onto the current `list1`, while `list1 = list1 + list2` creates a new list and assigns it to the variable name `list1`.  So yes, with mutable objects, `a += b` is not the same as `a = a + b`.

Comment: In terms of efficiency, you are better off doing the 'set default argument to `None`' thing because that way, you don't need to recreate the entire list every time you add a host, instead it will be appending to the existing list that is unique to each cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this SO post: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

When Python executes the following code:

```
def add_cloud(ID,coordinate,Hosts=[]):
    global CLOUDS
    CLOUDS += [Cloud(ID, coordinate,  Hosts)]
```

It creates a function object, and stores default parameter values that were specified in a tuple under the attribute `func_defaults`.  See:

```
>>> print add_cloud.func_defaults
([],)
```

So basically the default parameter is always referencing the same list.  And your clouds will all hold pointers to that same list too, so adding a host to one cloud will affect all others, including any new clouds that you might make in the future.

To prevent this, do the following instead:

```
def add_cloud(ID,coordinate,Hosts=None):
    if Hosts is None:
        Hosts = []
    global CLOUDS
    CLOUDS += [Cloud(ID, coordinate,  Hosts)]
```

There is also a [great effbot article](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You've used empty list syntax `[]` in a definition (`add_cloud`). That's a no-no. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22515832/3060280

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
def add_cloud(ID,coordinate,Hosts=[]):
```

The default value of the parameter `Hosts` is `[]`, but Python only evaluates that **one** time. So, the second time you call `add_cloud`, `Hosts` won't be assigned to `[]` again.

This causes that the list you are passing as argument when you are creating the object

```
CLOUDS += [Cloud(ID, coordinate,  Hosts)]
```

is the same on each call to `add_cloud`.

**What can you do?**

One thing would be the following validation:

```
def add_cloud(ID, coordinate, Hosts = None):
    if Hosts is None:
        Hosts = []
    ...
```

**Notes:** Remember to follow [Python naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).